# PHP5: How come an included function always echoes first if I call it?

Tags: php, include, echo

I've got two files here:

ToBeIncludedFile.php

```
<?php
function printOut(){
    echo "World!";
}
?>
```

MainFile.php

```
<?php
include("ToBeIncludedFile.php");

echo "Hello ".printOut();
?>
```

I would expect "Hello World!". Instead I get this: "World!Hello ".

I know if I write return instead of echo, then everything is fine. Is it because I'm echoing a function that is already echoing a string? But then why would it print out the string "World!" first and not throw an error?

Comment: Because the "calling echo" echoes the returned value of the function. The function returns nothing (null), so it echoes "Hello" after it has run  all the code inside the function (including the functions echo). Change the function to return a string instead of echoing it and you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it echos first, is because it is called, and *afterwards* are the strings "concatenated" (more on that in a second):

What you want in `ToBeIncludedFile.php` is `return "World!";`, not echo.

Right now, this is what happens:

- You include the file, which doesn't print anything, this is correct.
- You do a concatenation of the string "Hello" and the *return value* of `printOut()`. That means, first that function is called:
- printOut() executes and prints "World!", returning nothing.
- Your main script then concatenates "Hello" with nothing and prints that.

Comment: ...but I still don't get why the function executes first. There must be a reason behind why the creator of PHP said, the function has to execute first, right? Why is it necessary that the function executes first?

Comment: Because an expression first needs to execute all its parts, before being evaluated. Imagine having instead `echo 5 + max([10,2]);`. Before echo can print the sum of the two values, it *has to* execute `max`, otherwise it doesn't know what the maximum of the list is.